# Rewriting URL containing a '?'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewriting rule which transform :

```
 www.test.com/123456789
```

to

```
www.test.com/task.php?name=123456789
```

Now I am looking to do the same with a question mark before :

```
www.test.com/?123456789
```

I've tried :

```
RewriteRule ^\?([0-9]{10})$ task.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But it does not work : no erros, but not redirected to task.php

I think that the '?' may cause issue..

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you using any `RewriteCond` ? you have used `$1`  in the new URL but you havent captured the variable with `(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that in your `.htaccess` for `www.test.com/?123456789`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^$ task.php?name=%1 [L]
```

And by the way... `123456789` -> `[0-9]{9}` and not {10}
If 10 is important you can use that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\d{10})$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
RewriteRule ^\?([0-9]{10})$ task.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

To capture your number and pass it into the new URL

Comment: Surely that should be ^/\?([0-9]{10})$ task.php?name=$1 (i.e. with a '/' after the start of string anchor)